# Inkscape shape has no stroke

Tags: inkscape, stroke

I just freshly installed Inkscape 0.92 and when I draw an object like a rectangle, the stroke is invisible even though the settings seem to be correct:

[image]

As can be seen in the image, there is no stroke, even though opacity is set to 100% for stroke. The stroke also has width. In fact, if I change the wide the dashed marquee expands and contracts, but still no stroke is shown.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **alpha** channel is all the way down.

[image]

Alpha controls basically the same thing as opacity, but it is for that color specifically. Set it all the way up to have the stroke shown.

Comment: Yep, change your RGBA to 000000FF.  The last two digits should be FF for any solid colour